# ¿como hacer que un label siga al puntero, dentro de un jframe con un evento de mouse?

Tags: java, java-swing

he intentado una y otra vez mover un jlabel a la posición donde se encuentra el puntero. para esto he capturado las cordenadas del puntero y se  las he asignado a mi label.

```
    private void jPanel1MouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   
   ///coordenadas es un jlabel que me sirve para mostrar las coordenadas donde se encuentra el puntero
   coordenadas.setText(String.format("Sus coordenadas son: [%d ,%d]", evt.getX(), evt.getY()));
   x=evt.getX();
    y=evt.getY();

    ///llegador es mi label que deceo mover a la posicion donde se encuentra mi puntero
    llegador.setLocation(x,y);

}
```

pero resulta que el label "llegador" no cambia de posición (no se mueve).
si me ayudaran se los agradeceria bastante.

gracias de antemano

Comment: has un repaint del label, eso lo metes en un listener?

Comment: hice lo siguiente dentro del mismo código después de la ultima linea de código "llegador.repaint()" pero tampoco lo hace.

Comment: ¿como estás escuchando al mosue, con un MouseAdapter o un MouseMotionAdapter? Puede agregar la clase con la que escuchas al mouse, y donde agregas el MouseMotionAdapter al JPanel?

Comment: dentro de un MouseMotionAdapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tengo una app `Swing` a la que alguna vez le incluí una funcionalidad de ese estilo, con eventos de raton.

**Lo primero que tengo son dos variables globales:**

```
private Point location;
private MouseEvent myEvent;
```

**Mas adelante a un componente le aplico 2 listeners (*mousePressed y mouseDragged*):**

```
display.addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() {
  public void mousePressed( MouseEvent evt ) {
    myEvent = evt;
  }
} );

display.addMouseMotionListener( new MouseAdapter() {
  public void mouseDragged( MouseEvent evt ) {
    Component C = evt.getComponent();
    location = C.getLocation( location );
    int x = location.x - myEvent.getX() + evt.getX();
    int y = location.y - myEvent.getY() + evt.getY();
    display.setLocation( x, y );
  }
} );
```

De ese modo muevo (arrastro) el componente hasta donde sea que llegue el cursor dentro del contenedor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: muchisimas gracias bro!!